# D3 projection not setting cx property

Tags: javascript, csv, svg, d3.js, mapping

I have a map of the USA that I'm trying to display lat/lon points over. I've mashed together a few examples to get this far, but I've hit a wall. My points are in a csv file, which I'm not sure how to upload here, but it's just 65,000 rows of number pairs. For instance 31.4671154,-84.9486771.

I'm mostly following the example from Scott Murray's book [here](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000345/ch12.html).

I'm using the Albers USA projection.

```
var projection = d3.geo.albersUsa()
.scale(1200)
.translate([w / 2, h / 2]);
```

And setting up the landmarks as an svg group appended to the map container.

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
.attr("width", w)
.attr("height", h)
.on("click", stopped, true);

svg.append("rect")
.attr("class", "background")
.attr("width", w)
.attr("height", h)
.on("click", reset);                            

var g = svg.append("g");
var landmarks = svg.append("g")
```

I read the data and try to set circles at each lat/lon point.

```
d3.csv("./public/assets/data/landmark_latlon_edited.csv", function(error, latlon){
console.log(latlon);
landmarks.selectAll("circle")
  .data(latlon)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr({
    'fill': '#F00',
    'r': 3
  })
  .attr('cx', function(d){
      return projection([d.lon, d.lat][0]);
    })
  .attr('cy', function(d){
    return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[1];
  })
  .style({
    'opacity': .75
  });
```

});

Now, the problem is that the cx property is not receiving a value. When viewed in the inspector the circles don't show a cx, and, indeed, appear in the svg at the appropriate y values, but in a stacked column at x=0.

```
<circle fill="#F00" r="3" cy="520.8602676002965" style="opacity: 0.75;"></circle>
```

I found an old issue I thought might be related [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/1287) which states that the projection method will return null if you try to feed it values outside of its normal bounding box. I opened the csv in Tableau and saw a couple values that were in Canada or some U.S. territory in the middle of the Pacific (not Hawaii), and I removed those, but that didn't solve the problem.

I'm decidedly novice here, and I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but if anyone can help me figure out where to look I would greatly appreciate it. Lots of positive vibes for you. If I can add anything to clarify the problem please let me know.

Thanks,
Brian

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I updated to d3 v3.5.6.  Here is what I did to check for null values, so that you don't try to access the [0] position of null:

```
.attr("cx", function(d) {
        var coords = projection([d.lon, d.lat]);
        if (coords) {
            return coords[0];
        }
})
```

I'm sure there is a cleaner way to do this, but it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have a little error in your function generating `cx` values which messes it all up. It's just one parenthesis in the wrong place:

```
.attr('cx', function(d){
    return projection([d.lon, d.lat][0]);
})
```

By coding `[d.lon, d.lat][0]` you are just passing the first value of the array, which is `d.lon`, to the projection and are returning the result of `projection()` which is an array. Instead, you have to place the `[0]` outside the call of `projection()` because you want to access the value it returned. Check your function for `cy` where you got things right. Adjusting it as follows should yield the correct values for `cx`:

```
.attr('cx', function(d){
    return projection([d.lon, d.lat])[0];
})
```